# Swift. How to write UICollectionView in separate swift file other than ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I found a bundle of tutorials about how to use UICollectionView. But they just write them in ViewController. I want to know how to write UICollectionView in another swift file. Then call it in my ViewController class. Here is my UICollectionView codes.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var ImageNames: [String] = ["photo", "photo1", "photo2", "photo3"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let layout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 120)

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return ImageNames.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: ImageNames[indexPath.row]))
        cell.backgroundView = imageView
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        cell?.backgroundView = nil
    }

}
```

By the way, second question. In my code, I currently pass array to `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` function by making the array global. How can I pass the ImagesNames array to this function locally?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The important part is

```
collectionView.dataSource = self
collectionView.delegate = self
```

Which is telling your collection view where to find it's datasource / delegate methods such as `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

You should make a new class that has `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate` and create a lazy var of it in your view controller

So new class...

```
class MyDataController: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

  // all collection view stuff here

}
```

Then in your ViewController

```
lazy var dataController: MyDataController = {

    let dataController = MyDataController()

    return dataController
}()
```

and finally

```
collectionView.dataSource = self
collectionView.delegate = self
```

becomes

```
collectionView.dataSource = self.dataController
collectionView.delegate = self.dataController
```

Regarding your second question, you need to think carefully about how to store your data using MVC conventions. You can have a local array variable in your dataController that will control the information presented in the collectionView, but how to globally fetch and retain that information is a broad topic.

** Edit **

To follow up on the why lazy question...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let dataController:MyDataController = MyDataController()
    let layout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 120)

    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
}
```

Becomes, depending on choice something like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
}

// all other code

// then right at the bottom of your class

// MARK: - Properties

lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {

    let layout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 120)

    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.dataSource = self.dataController
    collectionView.delegate = self.dataController
    collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    return collectionView
}()

lazy var dataController: MyDataController = {

    let dataController = MyDataController()
    dataController.delegate = self
    // more setup if needed

    return dataController
}()
```

What I find handy about this is, your properties are always easy to find, easy to move around and easy to change. If I comment out the `addSubview` line in `viewDidLoad` that's enough in this case to stop the `collectionView` and `dataController` being initialised all together. Perhaps it's overkill for this example, but adopted holistically it saves a lot of time and produces clean readable oo code.

Comment: Why lazy? Seems like `let dataController = MyDataController()` would be preferable, unless you think the collection view will *only sometimes* be present

Comment: I prefer lazy because personally I think it's tidy. It lets you draws on variables as and when you need them and there's zero harm, maybe in the future something will change and this I've found is really readable and easily changed.... you're right though we don't need to... we could  also make the `collectionView` lazy and stick it's `dataController` inside there.. Always a question of preference... Lazy var is my preferred style and the person asking asked a style related question. I find sticking everything in `viewDidLoad` becomes unwieldy.

Comment: I agree but worth noting that `let dataController = MyDataController()` does not need to be in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Yeah definitely. Almost certainly fine to put it in with the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` but you may need a pointer to it to access it later.

Comment: I was talking about defining it as a property